# Metro App crash on Windows 10

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-8, windows-10

My XAML Metro App works fine on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 device.
Unfortunately it crashes on a Windows 10 device by binding a collectionviewsource on a huge listview with a lot of datatemplates.

```
Dim data As New CollectionViewSource()
data.IsSourceGrouped = True
data.Source = au.lkat.gruppern
data.ItemsPath = New PropertyPath("details")
lsvKatalog.DataContext = data
```

The following unhandled exception appears only above a certain amount of data.

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Für den Parameter "key" von "Public Default Property Item(key As Object) As Object" wurde kein Argument angegeben.
```

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I migrate from VS2012(Windows8) to VS2013(retarget to Windows8.1)
This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is as described above, it is a system bug as Windows 8 apps should work properly on Windows 10.

There are two things you can do - try to submit the bug to Microsoft (Feedback hub or feedback in Visual Studio could be used for that), try to build alternative way of achieving things that won't crash. For the second thing one would need much more detailed view in your app to give some particular advice.